# How to query a mongo collection with exclusive arguments

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In a js file I make the following query to retrieve all the games played by the user when he plays the White (it is a game where you play White or Black) and render them in a jade file

```
view.query('games', Game.model.find().sort('game.date').where('game.users.white', req.user.key).where('game.resign', ""));
```

It is working but I need to retrieve all the games played by the user when he plays the White or the Black, how can I use the OR operator ?

Thanks

Comment: Use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-or-conditions)?

Comment: In the main app.js I use to    db.collection('games').find( { $or: [ { "game.users.white": userId }, { "game.users.black": userId } ] } )    but it is not working in this js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is a .or in mongoose (which I guess you are using as driver)

```
view.query('games', Game.model.find().sort('game.date').or([{'game.users.white': req.user.key}, {'game.users.black': req.user.key}]).where('game.resign', ""));
```